# NLog TemplateParserException, expected '{' but found '\' instead in format?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I using NLog (4.7.2) in a project where I get the following exception in the NLog logfile:

```
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5324 Debug Watching path 'C:\DEVSTUFF\MyApp\Produkter\MyAppUtveckling\Solution\MyApp.Client.Main\bin\Debug' filter 'NLog.config' for changes.
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5324 Debug --- NLog configuration dump ---
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5324 Debug Targets:
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5513 Debug LogToService Target[LogToService]
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5513 Debug LogMessageEvent Target[communicationLogWindow]
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5633 Debug Rules:
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5633 Debug --- End of NLog configuration dump ---
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5853 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5942 Trace Scanning LogToServiceTarget 'LogToService Target[LogToService]'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5942 Trace  Scanning Property Layout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:52.5942 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6132 Trace   Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6132 Trace   Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6271 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6271 Trace   Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6271 Trace    Scanning Property Inner 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6561 Trace    Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6561 Trace     Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6561 Trace     Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6730 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6730 Trace   Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6910 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.6910 Trace   Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7039 Trace Scanning LogMessageEventTarget 'LogMessageEvent Target[communicationLogWindow]'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7039 Trace  Scanning Property Layout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7039 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7219 Trace   Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7219 Trace   Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7219 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7388 Trace   Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7388 Trace    Scanning Property Inner 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7498 Trace    Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7498 Trace     Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7668 Trace     Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7668 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7817 Trace   Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7817 Trace   Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.7817 Trace   Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8017 Info Found 22 configuration items
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8127 Debug Unused target checking is started... Rule Count: 0, Target Count: 2
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8127 Warn Unused target detected. Add a rule for this target to the configuration. TargetName: LogToService
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8296 Warn Unused target detected. Add a rule for this target to the configuration. TargetName: communicationLogWindow
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8296 Debug Unused target checking is completed. Total Rule Count: 0, Total Target Count: 2, Unused Target Count: 2
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8296 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${message}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8476 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8476 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${logger}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8595 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8595 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${level}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8595 Trace Initializing SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8805 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8805 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8924 Trace  Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.8924 Trace  Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9074 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9074 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9074 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${longdate}
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9253 Trace Initializing '${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9253 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9373 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9373 Trace  Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9373 Trace  Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9523 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9523 Trace  Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9523 Trace   Scanning Property Inner 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9697 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9697 Trace    Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9697 Trace    Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9872 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9872 Trace  Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9987 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9987 Trace  Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:52.9987 Trace Initializing LogMessageEvent Target[communicationLogWindow]
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0176 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Layouts.Layout>:
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0176 Trace Scanning LogMessageEventTarget 'LogMessageEvent Target[communicationLogWindow]'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0316 Trace  Scanning Property Layout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0316 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0475 Trace LogMessageEvent Target[communicationLogWindow] has 1 layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0475 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${message}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0655 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0655 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${logger}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0815 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0815 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${level}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0934 Trace Initializing SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.0934 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1094 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1094 Trace  Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1263 Trace  Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1263 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1403 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${literal}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1403 Trace Initializing Layout Renderer: ${longdate}
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1403 Trace Initializing '${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1583 Trace FindReachableObject<System.Object>:
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1583 Trace Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1583 Trace  Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1762 Trace  Scanning LongDateLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${longdate}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1762 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1872 Trace  Scanning UppercaseLayoutRendererWrapper 'Layout Renderer: ${uppercase}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1872 Trace   Scanning Property Inner 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:53.1872 Trace   Scanning SimpleLayout 'SimpleLayout=Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2073 Trace    Scanning Property Renderers 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer]' System.Collections.ObjectModel
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2073 Trace    Scanning LevelLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${level}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2183 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2183 Trace  Scanning LoggerNameLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${logger}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2183 Trace  Scanning LiteralLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${literal}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2362 Trace  Scanning MessageLayoutRenderer 'Layout Renderer: ${message}'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2362 Trace Initializing LogToService Target[LogToService]
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2362 Trace FindReachableObject<NLog.Layouts.Layout>:
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2538 Trace Scanning LogToServiceTarget 'LogToService Target[LogToService]'
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2538 Trace  Scanning Property Layout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}'' NLog.Layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2658 Trace  Scanning SimpleLayout ''${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}''
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2658 Trace LogToService Target[LogToService] has 1 layouts
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2658 Info Configuration initialized.
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2847 Info NLog, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.7.0.11381. Product version: 4.7.0+4d138800820311d0b60b6437f1dd2ed1d571d47d.
2020-07-03 15:41:53.2847 Debug Targets not configured for logger: MyAppKontext.Kontext
2020-07-03 15:42:51.3143 Debug Targets not configured for logger: GeneralLogger
2020-07-03 15:42:51.3143 Debug Targets not configured for logger: CommunicationLogger
2020-07-03 15:42:51.3143 Debug Targets not configured for logger: FileLogger
```

The C# code that trigger the Log function looks like this:

```cs
public void Log(LogData logData)
{
    SerlizeParameters(logData);

    var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
    logEvent.Level = logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel();
    logEvent.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logData, Formatting.Indented);
    logEvent.Properties.Add("logdata", logData);
    logEvent.Parameters = new object[1] { logData };
    _genLogger.Log(logEvent);
}
```

The nlog.config looks like this:

```xml
<targets>
    <target name="LogToService" xsi:type="LogToService"/>
    <target name="communicationLogWindow" xsi:type="LogMessageEvent"/>
    <target xsi:type="File"
    name="communicationFileLog"
    fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
    maxArchiveDays="5"
    maxArchiveFiles="10">
      <!--SkipCharsInParameterObject = Starting position within the serialized string -->
      <!--TakeCharsInParameterObject = Lengh of data(char) to serialize -->
      <!--TakeCharsInParameterObject = 0 - No serialization -->
      <!--TakeCharsInParameterObject = -1 - Serialize everything -->
      <!--FilterServiceMethodName = Exact name of servicemethods to listen on, comma(,) can be used to filter on more then 1 method. -->
      <!--FilterCallDirection = Send, Receive, ReceiveMQ, Unknown(all) -->
      <layout xsi:type="JsonNetLayout"
              SkipCharsInParameterObject="0"
              TakeCharsInParameterObject="1000"
              FilterServiceMethodName=""
              FilterCallDirection="Unknown"/>
   </target>
</targets>
<rules>
    <logger name="GeneralLogger" minlevel="Warn" writeto="LogToService"></logger>
    <logger name="CommunicationLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeto="communicationLogWindow"></logger>
</rules>
```

My custom target is never triggered, probably the exception is thrown right before.

I have tried to set the `logEvent.Message` to "test" but that does nothing. Why do i get this exception?

Regards

EDIT: When I turn off the structure `loggin(parseMessageTemplates="false")` I get this in the log file instead of the exception:

```
2020-07-03 16:46:04.4968 Debug Targets not configured for logger: MyAppKontext.Kontext
2020-07-03 16:46:16.7226 Debug Targets not configured for logger: GeneralLogger
2020-07-03 16:46:16.7226 Debug Targets not configured for logger: CommunicationLogger
2020-07-03 16:46:16.7356 Debug Targets not configured for logger: FileLogger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog is fine with assigning "blob"-data to `LogEventInfo.Message`-property. But if you also assign `LogEventInfo.Parameters` then NLog will try to parse the messsage and inject the parameters.

So just skip the `Parameters`-property, and `Message` will become a blob:

```
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
logEvent.Level = logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel();
logEvent.Message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logData, Formatting.Indented);
logEvent.Properties.Add("logdata", logData);
// Skip this -> logEvent.Parameters = new object[1] { logData };
_genLogger.Log(logEvent);
```

You could also inject the blob as format-parameter like this:

```
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
logEvent.Level = logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel();
logEvent.Message = "{0}";    // Blob formatting
logEvent.Properties.Add("logdata", logData);
logEvent.Parameters = new object[1] { JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logData, Formatting.Indented); };
_genLogger.Log(logEvent);
```

Another alternative is using message-templates like this (Will use NLog JsonSerializer to format logData):

```
_genLogger.Log(logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel(), "{@logdata}", logData);
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: Thanks but if I dont use the Properties to get my data to the custom target is there another way? I have seen something about withProperty but I suspect it is really the same thing? I want to be able to add anything to the message but at the same time provide data for the custom target, is this possible?

Comment: The alternative I found was to create 2 loggers, one for my custom targets that will add the object to the properties and one general logger to just get out the information in plain text without any properties. So instead of just logging the message to one logger I log it to 2. The nlog.config will decide how to handle the rest with files and custom targets. Is this a okay solution according to NLog standard?

Comment: @Banshee If you just skip assigning the `Parameters` then everything will work as expected (Just as shown in my answer). The alternative solution just makes use of message-template-logic and gives the same result (capture a property with name `"logdata"`). If you don't like the alternative solution, then just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send JSON in the message. The message is parsed as a message template (with `{0}` or `{Named}` tokens.)
The `Parameters` are used for creating the message, see it as a fancy  `string.Format`.

You could pass the data in the properties, as in your example but don't sent it also in the message or parameters.

So this is OK:

```cs
var logEvent = new LogEventInfo();
logEvent.Level = logData.LogLevel.ToLogLevel();
logEvent.Message = "normal message"
logEvent.Properties.Add("logdata", logData);
_genLogger.Log(logEvent);
```

Comment: logData is added to the properties so my LogToServiceTarget can unpack and send it to the service as is. But at the same time I want to make it possible to get the data to file if needed. A fast way would be to just convert the object to JSON and put it in the Message but as you say, there is a formater that will not like this. So if I still want to expose the entire content of logData to other targets like file, how would I do this? I saw that there is a parseMessageTemplates="false" but it seems to effect all NLog instanses.